# Change full calendar output?

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I am working on a full calendar on a webpage. Currently, the layout of each day block is:

```
Time
Title
Description
```

but I would like title goes first and then time. But I cannot find anywhere I can make this change in the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cal").fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            right: 'month,agendaDay'
        },
        aspectRatio: 2,
        editable: false,
        timeFormat: 'h:mmt{-h:mmt}',
        eventTextColor: 'black',
        eventBackgroundColor: '#FFFF77',
        allDayDefault: false,
        eventSources: [{
            url: 'path/to/fullcalendar',
            color: 'green',
            textColor: 'black'
            }],
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.find('.fc-event-title').html(event.title + "<br/>" + event.description).text();
        }
    });
});
```

So anyone can help me figure out where should I modify to make the change to swap title and time?

Thank you

Comment: @PaulTomblin Its a part of java application so I assumed someone worked on java may have experience with it.

Comment: Please format the code so it fits on the screen without too much scrolling.

Comment: Plus, you seem to use some existing application, but without telling us *what* you are using, noone will be able to help you, since we do not know what the function `fullCalendar` is.

Comment: There is no java code involved here, and not all Java programs use web front ends.  The java tag is misleading and wrong.

Comment: I guess he is using the jQuery extension [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). So it's javascript not java,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of `eventRender` you need to alter the element layout so the time comes after the title. Something like this:

```
eventRender : function(event, element) {
  var time = element.find('.fc-event-time').detach();
  element.find('.fc-event-title').after(time);
  ... any other code here ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @patrickmcgraw Thank you for the suggestion. It works. However, I found the out put was a little wired after doing this. in the output, the title is follow by a `"[Object object]"` string... do you have any idea about what is going on with that? Thank you

Comment: If you inspect the HTML where is the [Object object] string?

Comment: the string associates with the title. here is my code by the way `eventRender : function(event,element) {
             time = element.find('.fc-event-time').detach();
             
             element.find('.fc-event-title').after(time);
             element.find('.fc-event-title').html(event.title +"<br/>"+ time +"<br/>"+ event.description).text();

            }`

Comment: Ah, I get it. Change it to this. `eventRender : function(event,element) { time = element.find('.fc-event-time').detach(); element.find('.fc-event-title').after(time); element.append("<div>" + event.description + "</div>"); }`